# CListView in Yii Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, yii, yii-components

I have started working on yii framework and I am following the yii blog tutorial to learn basics of yii framework in this tutorial they have used a ClistView in posts view but i am getting an exception [image]

This is the code that i have used in view file:

```
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Posts'=>array('index'),
    $model->post_id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List Posts', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create Posts', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'Update Posts', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->post_id)),
    array('label'=>'Delete Posts', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->post_id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('label'=>'Manage Posts', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<?php if( !empty($_GET['tag']) ) : ?>
<h1>Posts Tagged with <em><?php echo CHtml::encode($_GET['tag']); ?></em></h1>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model,
    'itemView' => '_view',
    'template' => "{items}\n{pager}",
));
```

This is what my PostsController contains:

```
/**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $post = $this->loadModel($id);
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$post,
        ));
    }

/**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        if( $this->_model === NULL )
        {
            if( Yii::app()->user->isGuest )
                $condition = 'post_status='.Posts::STATUS_PUBLISHED.' or post_status='.Posts::STATUS_ARCHIVED;
            else
                $condition = '';
                
            $this->_model = Posts::model()->findByPk($id, $condition);
                
            if($this->_model === NULL)
                throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');
        }
        
        return $this->_model;
    }
```

I can't find out where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dataProvider` property of a `CListView` should be a `CActiveDataProvider` (or a different data provider). Try

```
'dataProvider' => new CActiveDataProvider($model),
```

instead.